# ValueError: learning_rate must be greater than 0 but was 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, hyperopt

i tried to tune hyperparameters of scikit GradientBoostingRegressor model using the Hyperopt optimizer. I set search space for learning_rate parameter in the range [0.01, 1] by many ways (for example :

```
'learning_rate': hp.quniform('learning_rate', 0.01, 1, 0.05)
```

or as simple array `[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.1]` but when I run the code hyperopt start to calculation and I get the error " ValueError: learning_rate must be greater than 0 but was 0".

I do not know what is problem in the code because zero value is not in the parameter's scope. How zero value come to function?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank You in advance.

Below I attach the related code. NOTE: The code working without problems for RandomForestRegressor and ExtraTreesRegressor methods (estimators).

```
# Varying parameter definition
varying_parameter='All - by Hyperopt'
varying_parameter_item = 'Complete search space'

# Optimization function definition
def gb_mse_cv(params, random_state=random_state, cv=kf, X=train_features, y=train_labels):

    # the function gets a set of variable parameters in "param"
    params = {'n_estimators': int(params['n_estimators']), 
              'max_depth': int(params['max_depth']),
              'min_samples_split': int(params['min_samples_split']),
              'max_features': int(params['max_features']),
              'learning_rate': int(params['learning_rate']),
              'min_samples_leaf': int(params['min_samples_leaf']),
              'subsample': int(params['subsample'])}

    # we use this params to create a new LGBM Regressor
    model = GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)

    # and then conduct the cross validation with the same folds as before
    score = -cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=cv, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", n_jobs=-1).mean()

    return score

# possible values of parameters
space={'n_estimators': hp.quniform('n_estimators', 50, 250, 1),
       'max_depth' : hp.quniform('max_depth', 2, 20, 1),
       'min_samples_split' : hp.quniform('min_samples_split', 2, 10, 1),
       'max_features' : hp.quniform('max_features', 1, train_features.shape[1], 1),
       'learning_rate': hp.quniform('learning_rate', 0.01, 1, 0.05),
       'min_samples_leaf': hp.quniform('min_samples_leaf', 1, 10, 1),
       'subsample': hp.quniform('subsample', 0.6, 1, 0.1)}

# This will contain contain logging information
trials = Trials()

best=fmin(fn=gb_mse_cv, # function to optimize
          space=space, 
          algo=tpe.suggest, # optimization algorithm, hyperotp will select its parameters automatically
          max_evals=n_iter, # maximum number of iterations
          trials=trials, # logging
          rstate=np.random.RandomState(random_state) # fixing random state for the reproducibility
         )

print("Best MAE {:.3f} params {}".format( gb_mse_cv(best), best))

# computing the score on the test set
model = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=random_state, n_estimators=int(best['n_estimators']), max_depth=int(best['max_depth']),
              min_samples_split=int(best['min_samples_split']), max_features=int(best['max_features']))

# Opening output .csv log file
of_connection=open(out_file, 'a')
writer=csv.writer(of_connection)

# Print model parameters
print(' ')
print(model.get_params())

t0=time.time()

# Train the model on training data
model.fit(train_features, train_labels);

# Train time calculation
train_time=time.time()-t0

t0=time.time()

# Test the model on test data
predictions = model.predict(test_features)

# Test time calculation
test_time=time.time()-t0

# Print train and test time
print('Train time=:', round(train_time, 2), ' s')
print('Test time=:', round(test_time, 2), ' s')

# Model metrics calculations    
MAE=mean_absolute_error(test_labels, predictions)
MSE=mean_squared_error(test_labels, predictions)
RMSE=math.sqrt(MSE)
R2=r2_score(test_labels, predictions)

errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
mape = 100 * (errors / test_labels)
accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)

# K-Fold cross-validation
cv_score=-cross_val_score(model, train_features, train_labels, cv=kf, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", n_jobs=-1).mean()

# Model metrics print
print('MAE=:', round(MAE, 6), 'W.')
print('MSE=:', round(MSE, 6), 'W.')
print('RMSE=:', round(RMSE, 6), 'W.')
print('R2=:', round(R2, 6), '.')
print('Accuracy (100-MAPE))=', round(accuracy, 6), '%.')
print('Cross-validation MAE score=', round(cv_score, 6), ' W.')

# Model parameters importances definitions
Irradiance_importance = model.feature_importances_[0]
Temperature_importance = model.feature_importances_[1]
Clearness_index_importance = model.feature_importances_[2]
Hour_of_day_importance = model.feature_importances_[3]
Previous_power_importance = model.feature_importances_[4]

# Model parameters importances print
print(model.feature_importances_)

# Write results to .csv log output file
writer.writerow([datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), model_code, method, varying_parameter,
                model.get_params()['loss'], model.get_params()['learning_rate'],
                model.get_params()['n_estimators'], model.get_params()['subsample'], 
                model.get_params()['criterion'], model.get_params()['min_samples_split'],
                model.get_params()['min_samples_leaf'], model.get_params()['min_weight_fraction_leaf'],   
                model.get_params()['max_depth'], model.get_params()['min_impurity_decrease'],    
                model.get_params()['min_impurity_split'], model.get_params()['init'],
                model.get_params()['random_state'], model.get_params()['max_features'],
                model.get_params()['alpha'], model.get_params()['verbose'], 
                model.get_params()['max_leaf_nodes'], model.get_params()['warm_start'], 
                model.get_params()['presort'], model.get_params()['validation_fraction'], 
                model.get_params()['n_iter_no_change'], model.get_params()['tol'],
                MAE, MSE, RMSE, R2, accuracy, cv_score,
                Irradiance_importance, Temperature_importance, 
                Clearness_index_importance, Hour_of_day_importance, Previous_power_importance, 
                train_time, test_time])

print('Finish case ', varying_parameter, '= ', varying_parameter_item)
print('-----------------------------------------------------')
print(' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cast your learning rates to an integer with `int()`, so Python rounded down to 0. You turned, say, `0.001` into an integer so Python rounds it down to `0`.

The problem is this line:

```
'learning_rate': int(params['learning_rate'])
```

Turn it into:

```
'learning_rate': params['learning_rate']
```

Comment: Dear Nicolas, Thank You on answer. Please, suggest me how to solve this issue and set the real number in range [0.01, 1] in this case.

Comment: Hi, please check the last line. You need to remove the `int()` call.

Comment: Dear Nicolas, Yes it was problem. I have removed int() call and now all works well. Thank You much on Your help. Best regards.

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. __If you want to say "thank you," vote and accept that person's answer__. _READ_: [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Note, I found the same unnecessary `int` issue on the `subsample` parameter as on  `learning_rate` parameter when running through the above code example.  I replaced `'subsample': int(params['subsample'])` with `'subsample': params['subsample']`.